# if we have two html elements named button how we can select the specific element and add style to it using javascript using query selector

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <style>
        .btn {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .btn-clear {
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="remove-item btn-link text-red">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
    </button>
    <button id="clear" class="btn-clear"><b>Clear All</b></button>

    <script>
        const clearButton = document..querySelector(('button'));
        clearButton.style.color = 'red';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by class, as the CSS in this code does - you'd want something like `button.someClassUniqueToTheIntendedButten` in your querySelector

Answer (score 2):

you can do this task using button id

example->

```
const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear');
clearButton.style.color = 'red';
```